# Join data.frames by id where the id is the name of the data frame, and keep those ids in the rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data.frames where the names of the data.frames contain the ID as well as the 'grouping' characteristic. I want to join the data.frames that share the 'characteristic' part of the name, and keep the ids as row ids on this new data.frame. It has been difficult to put into words, here is a MRE:

```
trying <- list(" 8 type1"= data.frame(values = c(1:3), date =c("2015-08-08","2015-08-07","2015-08-06")),
           " 8 type2"= data.frame(values = c(4:6), date =c("2015-03-04","2015-03-03","2015-03-02")),
           " 9 type1"= data.frame(values = c(3:5), date =c("2015-05-03","2015-05-02","2015-05-01")),
           " 9 type2"= data.frame(values = c(2:4), date =c("2015-02-01","2015-01-31","2015-01-30")))
```

My expected output is a list of two data.frames joined by types, where the ids are kept as rows:

```
tryingmodified <- list("type1" = data.frame(id = c(8,8,8,9,9,9), values = c(1:3,3:5), date = c("2015-08-08","2015-08-07","2015-08-06", "2015-05-03","2015-05-02","2015-05-01")),
                   "type2" = data.frame(id = c(8,8,8,9,9,9), values = c(4:6,2:4), date = c("2015-03-04","2015-03-03","2015-03-02", "2015-02-01","2015-01-31","2015-01-30")))
```

Note that my actual data is much larger than this (more rows, more data.frames, and more columns), and the actual names are not 'typeX' but the general structure prevails `'space INT space TEXT'`: ("`8 type1`"). So any solution that is easily extensible is desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using dplyr, you get your result as a dataframe, but not as a list, like in tryingmodified. I'm not sure if that is an issue.

```
trying <- list(" 8 type1"= data.frame(values = c(1:3), date =c("2015-08-08","2015-08-07","2015-08-06")),
     " 8 type2"= data.frame(values = c(4:6), date =c("2015-03-04","2015-03-03","2015-03-02")),
     " 9 type1"= data.frame(values = c(3:5), date =c("2015-05-03","2015-05-02","2015-05-01")),
     " 9 type2"= data.frame(values = c(2:4), date =c("2015-02-01","2015-01-31","2015-01-30")))


library(dplyr) # dplyr version 0.43
df <- bind_rows(trying, .id = "ids") %>% 
      mutate(id = gsub(" type.", "", ids), type = gsub("^ [0-9] ", "", ids)) %>% 
      select(-ids) %>% 
      select(id, type, everything())
df

Source: local data frame [12 x 4]

      id  type values       date
   (chr) (chr)  (int)      (chr)
1      8 type1      1 2015-08-08
2      8 type1      2 2015-08-07
3      8 type1      3 2015-08-06
4      8 type2      4 2015-03-04
5      8 type2      5 2015-03-03
6      8 type2      6 2015-03-02
7      9 type1      3 2015-05-03
8      9 type1      4 2015-05-02
9      9 type1      5 2015-05-01
10     9 type2      2 2015-02-01
11     9 type2      3 2015-01-31
12     9 type2      4 2015-01-30
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not pasting the whole script to do this but just the major steps

First of all, for each of the data frame, extract the names by splitting it and use `assign` and `rbind`to assign that  dataframe with the values.

```
lapply(1:length(trying),function(x){
    newDFName <- strsplit(sub("^\\s+","",names(trying[x]))," ")[[1]][2]
    #use newDFName along with assign and rbind to assign the new data frame the rows
})
```